# Changing value if they meet a condition, dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of phone numbers, some of the column values have ';' at the start:

```
Phone
-------
890734687; 098766576565
890734687
;890734687
234873576; 987982346
;9088327427; 897234632
```

What I need to end up with is:

```
Phone
-------
890734687; 098766576565
890734687
890734687
234873576; 987982346
9088327427; 897234632
```

Can I use a for loop?

```
for num in df['Phone']
    if num[0] == ';'
        # what next?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `str.lstrip`:

```
df.Phone = df.Phone.str.lstrip(';')
```

Now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
                     Phone
0  890734687; 098766576565
1                890734687
2                890734687
3     234873576; 987982346
4    9088327427; 897234632
```

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly do this:

```
df['Phone'] = df['Phone'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip(';'))
```